# Netty IdleStateEvent doesn't raise READER_IDLE on server

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, netty

I'm creating a Netty (4.0.14 Final) client/server application with SSL Sockets and I am trying to implement an IdleStateEvent so that I can know when my clients or server goes offline.

The problem is, READER_IDLE does not work on the server. I'm pasting here snippets of the code.

**SocketInitializer**

```
public class SocketInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    SSLEngine engine = SslContextFactory.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
    engine.setUseClientMode(false);

    pipeline.addLast("idleHandler", new IdleStateHandler(30, 0, 0));
    pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
    pipeline.addLast(new SocketDecoder(), new SocketHandler());
}
}
```

**SocketHandler**

```
(...)
@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if(evt instanceof IdleState) {
        IdleState e = (IdleState) evt;
        if(e == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            System.out.println("It's idle!");
        }
    }
}
(...)
```

Now, I've tried to have the `userEventTriggered()` method both overridden on the `IdleStateHandler` class and on the `SslHandler` class (one at a time, of course :)), and neither of these options work. I have the exact same pipeline on the client with the `userEventTriggered()` on the `SocketHandler` class, but only triggering the WRITER_IDLE, and it works!

Is there anything that I am missing? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if it is of instance IdleStateEvent and if so cast it and check its state().

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if(evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        IdleStateEvent e = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
        if(e.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            System.out.println("It's idle!");
        }
    }
}
```

See the example in the javadocs:
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.java#L77

Comment: Oh dear god. Now I feel dumb :(
I had that same `IdleStateEvent` on the client side, and didn't manage to see my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, now I've got another (almost the same) problem. That event is only triggered when, per example, I remove the cable from the client machine. If I do a _CTRL+C_ Netty fails to trigger that event...

Comment: That's probably why the connection is closed and channelInactive() event has been triggered already?

Comment: The connection remains active. Let's say I have a timeout of 10 seconds; if I remove the network cable and wait more than 10 seconds the event is not triggered, but if I reconnect the cable in the meantime, all the messages pending in the disconnected machine are flushed onto the network. So the connection is somewhat still active, but the READER_IDLE is not triggered. Still not sure as why this happens...